# How to figure out what textvariable is used?

Tags: adobe-indesign

When I insert a text variable such as "chapter number", I get the respective value and only know it *is* a variable due to the barely visible frame around it. But how can I figure out afterwards *what* variable is inserted here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose "edit in text mode" from the text frame's context menu or hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>, there you'll see the variable name used.

[image: Text mode]